# ColdFusion MX User-Agent Cross-Site Scripting vulnerabilites

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

we recently had a webinspect on our application. we got an issue of User-Agent Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability , in the below GET Request we can see that the malicious script " alert(097531) "
got inserted into the User-Agent variable and we are not sure how that script getting inserted into the user agent field when we ran the webinspect scan.  could you please suggest us how to restrict the some intruder inserts malicious scripts into user agent variable. and the some url hitting badfile.cfm which is not present in the folder.  how do i restrict the url so that it will not hit to some badfile.
please find the below Request and Response parameters:

Request:

```
    GET /test/badfile123.cfm HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: <script>alert(097531)</script>
    Host: ebizweb2.stage.att.com
    Referer: https://www.exdomain.com/page.CFM?
    CAT=TRADSEARCH
    Accept: */*
    Pragma: no-cache
```

Response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Date: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 17:52:54 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_jk/1.2.32
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 2758
    ...TRUNCATED...font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">
    <script>alert(098531)</script></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <t...TRUNCATED...
```

Comment: Something on your website is outputting CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT without correctly encoding it. You need to use functions like [HtmlEditFormat](http://cfdocs.org/HtmlEditFormat) and/or [JsStringFormat](http://cfdocs.org/JsStringFormat) whenever you are outputting any user-derived variables (well, really for all variables, but security-wise it's about what a user can control). In this specific example, it seems your 404 error page is what's doing it, which may or not be controlled by CF, but don't settle with just checking/changing that one file).

Comment: Is this the bug? http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2011-0733/

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, see if you can upgrade to the latest version of ColdFusion. XSS attacks are the tip of the iceberg. There are a [considerable amount of other attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project) to which you could be (and most likely are) vulnerable and CF 10 and 11 have new functionality to address them.

For now, you need to implement the [OWASP Enterprise Security API](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) (ESAPI) if you can.

[Download](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/downloads/list) the ESAPI-1.4.5a.jar file from their Google Code repo. You can't use the 2.1 version since CF 6 won't run on the latest version of Java. This file is included in CF 8 and 9 via a hotfix.

In your application.cfm (or .cfc), set

`<cfset application.xssEncoder = createObject("java", "org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI").encoder() />`

Now, instead of `HTMLEditFormat()` or `JSStringFormat()`, you can use `application.xssEncoder.encodeForHTML()` or `application.xssEncoder.encodeForJavaScript()`. These functions provide a higher level of encoding than the older native CF functions. In fact, ColdFusion 11 has deprecated `HTMLEditFormat()`.

You can read the [Java Docs](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/1.4.2/index.html) and get a list of all of the available encoders.

You can also keep an eye on [this project](http://damonmiller.github.io/esapi4cf/tutorials/Encoding.html), where I'm going to add a pile of documentation related to these functions in the near future.

**HOWEVER**, since this looks like your HEADERs were attacked, it could be a [CRLF attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Splitting/Smuggling_%28OWASP-DV-016%29) and not an XSS attack. Take a read of that page and see if it applies.